# Unable to install Ubuntu on Asus F551MA

Tags: wireless, kernel, asus

It's not possible to install either Ubuntu 14.04.1 or Ubuntu 14.10 on Asus F551MA, it goes kernel panic, switching back to text console and brutally freezes.

Checking on launchpad, I found it's a bug which should have been fixed with the August-version of the kernel. If I remember well, it should occur when wifi card is accessed and the wifi scan process begins.

The problem is exactly this: how could I install Ubuntu 14.04.1 with the latest kernel instead of the one which comes with the .iso?

Regards

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download daily build on [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/trusty/daily-live/current/). This build should contain latest packages available in repositories - therefore it might help you to solve your problem.